# MatLab serial fscanf reading long int from arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, long-integer, scanf

I am currently having issues reading a 32bit integer sent through serial from Arduino to MatLab.

According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fscanf.html?searchHighlight=serial%20fscanf) for serial fscanf, assuming I interpreted it correctly, the format 
A = fscanf(obj,'format',size) reads the number of values specified by size. 
so, I have

```
flushinput(handles.s);
disp('Buffer was flushed');
fprintf(handles.s,'%s','M0');
disp('M0 was sent');

for j = 1:6
    while (handles.s.BytesAvailable == 0) 
    end
    disp('pausing');
    pause(0.1);
    disp('stopped pausing');
    CurrentInput = fscanf(handles.s,'%c', 1 );
if CurrentInput == ' ' 
    disp('pausing');
    pause(0.1);
    disp('stopped pausing');
    databit = fscanf(handles.s,'%i',5);% reads four bytes and stores it as an integer
    disp(databit);
    disp(handles.s.BytesAvailable);
else
    disp('Error communicating with arduino');

end
handles.coefficients(j) = databit; % stores the calibration bytes inside the handles object
guidata(hObject,handles);
disp(handles.coefficients(j));
end
end
```

Which outputs the folowing

```
Buffer was flushed
M0 was sent
pausing
Buffer was flushed
M0 was sent
pausing
stopped pausing
pausing
stopped pausing
       45583

    30

       45583

pausing
stopped pausing
pausing
stopped pausing
       39633

    24

       39633

pausing
stopped pausing
pausing
stopped pausing
       28291

    18

       28291

pausing
stopped pausing
pausing
stopped pausing
       26021

    12

       26021

pausing
stopped pausing
pausing
stopped pausing
       32164

     6

       32164

pausing
stopped pausing
pausing
stopped pausing
       28343

     0

       28343
```

Which does what I want it to , but I don't understand why.

Now, I initially tested with

```
databit = fscanf(handles.s,'%i',4);% reads four bytes and stores it as an integer
```

Because I thought it would read 4 bytes (32 bits) and convert that as a long int. but realised soon enough the function had a will of its own and was reading digits or something...

Then how can I read a specified number of bytes (4) from the input buffer and convert them to an long int (32bits)?

Here is the snipet of arduino code that is relevent, for your interest. Essentially, we are reading coefficients from the register of 2 sensors through I2C. Then converting the bytes as long integers that are sent over serial to matlab.

```
//*********************************************************************************************************
// SERIAL
// Function to send an integer to MATLAB after converting it to a string and concatenating it with a character
// Parameters: 
//   >> data_label_character: A character defining the data that is to be sent after ()
//   >> data_integer: Integer holding the data to be sent to MATLAB 
// Return: None
////////Notes:
// This function is mainly used to send the capacitance, pressure, and temperature data to MATLAB
//*********************************************************************************************************
void send_MATLAB_integer_data(char data_label_character, uint32_t data_integer){
  Serial.print(data_label_character); // Send the defining label to MATLAB
  Serial.print(data_integer); // Follow the label by the corresponding data
}

//*********************************************************************************************************
// SERIAL 
// Function to transmit the data to MATLAB while conducting a delay for a certain amount of time
// Parameters: 
//   >> total_wait_period: The period of the delay to be conducted
//   >> maximum_data_conversion_wait: The maximum interval of time between two 
//      data points (a property of the devices on the bus and their ADCs) 
// Return: None
////////Notes:
// The conversion mode for the AD7162 assumed in this function is the Single Conversion mode
// The general assumption in this function is that the conversion time chosen for the AD7152 is 
// longer (60ms) than the conversion time of the temperature (10ms) and pressure (10ms) from the MS5803
// It is advised that the maximum_data_conversion_wait to be the actual conversion time plus several milliseconds for safety
//*********************************************************************************************************
void transmit_data_and_wait(unsigned long total_wait_period, unsigned long maximum_data_conversion_wait, int AD_channel_number, int OSR_temp, int OSR_press){
  unsigned long start_time; // The time at which the wait and transmit algorithm is to start

  // Keep looping until reaching the point in time where if you do the next conversion 
  // you will exceed the specified wait time
  start_time = millis(); // Store the start time 

  while(total_wait_period - (millis() - start_time) >  maximum_data_conversion_wait){
    AD_request_capacitance(AD_channel_number); // Function to request data from the AD7152 
    send_MATLAB_integer_data('P', MS_read_pressure(OSR_press)); // Send MATLAB the pressure value you read 
    send_MATLAB_integer_data('T', MS_read_temperature(OSR_temp)); // Function to read the temperature from the AD7152  
    send_MATLAB_integer_data('C', AD_read_requested_capacitance(AD_channel_number)); // Send temperature data here   

  }

  // If broke out of the loop before total_wait_period is complete, loop until it is complete
  while(total_wait_period - (millis() - start_time) > 0){}
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for [`Serial.print`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print). It does't print/transmit raw data. It converts numeric values to strings and send those. Either use something other than `Serial.print` (e.g., [`Serial.write`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write)) or use `'%s'` in your Matlab code.

Comment: Thanks for your input Horchler. I went through the arduino documentation. Then, if I would like to send an unsigned 32 bit integer. would I have to use serial.write(data_integer) or serial.write(data_integer, 4) ? the documentation states that  I can send a buffer of bytes. Is a uint_32 stored as a pointer to the first byte?...